# Indexing an interval of words on top of every page

Tags: header-footer, book-design, dictionaries

Friends, I'm curious on how to do the following in LaTeX:

Dictionaries have two words on the top of each page, meaning the interval of words to be found on that specific page, e.g.,

[image: Dictionary]

In the figure, **analyst** refers to the *lower bound* (the first word), and **ancillary** refers to the *upper bound* (the last word) in this page.

I was wondering of how we could achieve something similar in LaTeX. Let's say we have the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{description}
    \item[adequate] \lipsum[1]
    \item[adhere] \lipsum[2]
    \item[adherence] \lipsum[3]
    \item[adhesion] \lipsum[4]
    \item[adhesive] \lipsum[5]
    \item[adjacent] \lipsum[6]
    \item[adjective] \lipsum[1]
    \item[adjoin] \lipsum[2]
    \item[adjourn] \lipsum[3]
    \item[adjournment] \lipsum[4]
    \item[adjunt] \lipsum[5]
    \item[adjust] \lipsum[6]
\end{description}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: My example]

For this page, I expect to see both **adequate** and **adhesive** in the top of the page (first and last items on the page, respectively). The same rule applies to the rest of the pages. **Update:** I should've mentioned that I'm curious of an "automatic" way of choosing which words will be set in the page headers. `=)`

Any ideas?

Comment: Section 10 of the `fancyhdr` documentation shows how to do this.

Comment: @Alan: Interesting, thanks for mentioning. In fact, I was looking for something like an automatic procedure to look which words are the first and last in the current page and then set them in the header. `fancyhdr` solves the second part (how to put them in there), I wonder how could we solve the first one. `=)`

Comment: It's all in there.  See my posted answer.

Comment: @Alan: my bad, I probably misread the documentation. `;-)`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a worked up example based on section 10 of the [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) documentation:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% empty \sectionmark
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
% create a command to create marks and collapse them if they are identical
\newcommand{\mymarks}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\leftmark}{\rightmark}}
{\rightmark} % if equal
{\rightmark--\leftmark}} % if not equal 
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\mymarks} 
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\thepage}
% define a wrapper on the description environment to add the marks
% this part is quick and dirty; it would be better to define one's own
% environment to do this, but the basic idea is the same: you need
% to add the \markboth command to each dictionary entry
\def\ditem[#1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}\item[#1]}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{description}
    \ditem[adequate] \lipsum[1]
    \ditem[adhere] \lipsum[2]
    \ditem[adherence] \lipsum[3]
    \ditem[adhesion] \lipsum[4]
    \ditem[adhesive] \lipsum[5]
    \ditem[adjacent] \lipsum[6]
    \ditem[adjective] \lipsum[1]
    \ditem[adjoin] \lipsum[2]
    \ditem[adjourn] \lipsum[3]
    \ditem[adjournment] \lipsum[4]
    \ditem[adjunt] \lipsum[5]
    \ditem[adjust] \lipsum[6]
\end{description}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Absolutely fantastic, Alan! Thanks a million! `=)`