# dictionary header for subsections

Tags: sectioning, header-footer

I want to achieve a dictionary header for the subsections of a page (not for the whole section).

Imagine the header should looks like this:

```
subsectionname 1.1 - subsectionname 1.2                         SECTIONNAME 1
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Doing this is some not-so-stable way is easy. But getting this right reliably correct might be hard. I'll test some things. Also this will take a lot of space if you really want to include the section and subsection titles, which might not be what you want.

Comment: The problem is detecting whether the current subsection starts at the top of the page or whether some of the previous subsection carries over. Also it might be that a subsection doesn't start at the top of the page, but still is the only subsection which's content is on this page, because everything else on this page is from the section.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. So it is very difficult to achieve this? Sad :(. I really would like to have a header like this.

Comment: At least I can't think of a reliable automatic way, that doesn't mean that there is none, only that I can't think of one...

Comment: I have got an idea. What do you think about reading the .toc file into memory with LuaLateX to generate the appropriate headers from the information.

Comment: We don't need to do it in that way, I could create some engine-independent two-pass solution with the same functionality, but processing the page headers that way seems tedious. I got a not-so-good solution that's working in one pass, but it has the already mentioned pitfalls.

Comment: I'm a Tex newbie. Why is the two-pass solution tedious?

Comment: Mainly because it needs two passes, also I'd have to write a lot of code and would have to be careful to not accidentally break other stuff. If I can manage the full functionality just with the mark-mechanism of (e-)TeX, that'd be much better.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your help and your efforts. I really enjoy learning from you :)

Comment: And even with the two-pass mechanism, I have no idea how I could tell whether a subsection was the first thing on a page or not (without hacking the `\subsection` macro). If I have to: Which class are you using?

Comment: I am using the article class.

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26122/indexing-an-interval-of-words-on-top-of-every-page)?

Comment: No, thank you very much.